# slice last few characters

Tags: actionscript

How do I remove the last 4 characters in a string?

'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
to
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv'

Answer: slice(0,-4)

Comment: +1 for adding the answer. From API docs "If endIndex is a negative number, the ending point is determined by counting back from the end of the string, where -1 is the last character"

Comment: @Johnyang Props for **putting your answer in your question**. The OCD in me is also asking to **see your answer as an accepted answer too** *that is, as an answer with the little green check next to it*. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

yourString = yourString.substring( 0, yourString.length - 4 ) would also work, if you need more practice typing and want your cpu to work harder.